# How can I achieve true randomness in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a small script that will randomly place an item on my page every 25 to 60 seconds.

The below code will randomly add the div to my page, but every occurrence after that is executed at the exact same time.

For instance, if the script begins at 44 seconds, it will add a new div every 44 seconds, and not randomly.

How can I achieve true randomness?

```
var contentDiv = ['firstDiv','secondDiv'];
function popDiv(min, max) {
    var timedDiv =  contentDiv[Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)];
    jQuery( "#" + timedDiv ).fadeIn( "slow" ).delay(4000).fadeOut("slow");
}

popDiv(1, contentDiv.length - 1)

setInterval(function(){
    popDiv(1, contentDiv.length - 1);
},  
Math.round(Math.random() * (60000 - 15000)) + 15000);
```

Comment: you can't change the interval delay after it's been set, so... maybe an interval isn't what you want.

Comment: Use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, and call it every time popDiv gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the general principle:

```
let maxTime = 60000,
    minTime = 25000,
    doSomething = function () {
      // do something...
      setTimeout(function(){
        doSomething();
      }, Math.random() * (maxTime - minTime) + minTime)
   };
doSomething();
```

Comment: Thank you. A little rearranging and it is working as expected.

Comment: @FGatlin, glad I could help. Happy coding!